# How can I make a sum of numbers in a while loop then print the result?

Tags: java, while-loop, numbers, sum

I need to sum all numbers so `sum = sum + i` but I have no idea why I don't get the expected result

So the task is: use the while loop to calculate the sum of all numbers from 1 to 1000,  make it print the sum and not the intermediate values.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int i = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    while (i <= 1000) {
        sum = sum + i;
        ++i;
    }
    System.out.print(sum);
}
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: What did you expect? And what did you get instead?

Comment: Well, code you gave results in sum equal to 500500, which is correct result.

Comment: Assuming your code is correct, it can be simplified by using a for loop: `int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
 sum += i;
}
System.out.print(sum);`

Comment: What @mkrakhin said; you sum all ints from 1 to n, therefore the result is n * (n + 1) / 2, which gives 500500. Expected. So what did you expect if not that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum the numbers in a given range you can use the 
Gauss sum formular.

Which is the following:

```
(n * (n + 1)) / 2
```

Means: (RANGE * (MAX_VALUE + 1)) / 2 for explanation see:

http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.02.06/jo1.html
http://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/?PageSpeed=noscript

In your case of summing 1 to 1000: (1000 * 1001) / 2

If you want to sum for example from 500 to 1000 you can change the formular to:

```
 (501 * 1500) / 2
```

You can create a method like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{

    public static double sumRange(double begin, double end) {
        return ((end - (begin-1)) * (end + begin) ) / 2;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(sumRange(1, 1000));
        System.out.println(sumRange(500, 1000));
        System.out.println(sumRange(20, 300));
    }
}
```

Working Example:

http://ideone.com/G7wgjQ

Output:

Success time: 0.09 memory: 320320 signal:0
500500.0
375750.0
44960.0

To check the results you can use wolframalpha:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_500%5E1000+n

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `++i;` to `i++;`. I used your code and made the swapped, it worked for me. The `++` before or after is critical, it determines when you increment `i`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
public class Main
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  int sum = 0,i = 1;
  // Use a while loop to calculate the sum of 1 to 1000
  while (i <= 1000)
  {
    sum+=i;
    i++;
  }
  System.out.println(sum);
 }
}
```